# Simplifying equation of a cone's volume, radius, height when height equals $2\cdot \rm{radius}$

Tags: geometry

I have a cone shape that has $2\cdot \rm{radius} = \rm{height}$. When taking the formula for a cone and its volume,

$$h = \frac{3V}{π \cdot r^2},$$

I'd like to rewrite this to infer $h$ when $V$ is given. How do I simplify this? Some pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $r$ with $\frac h2$:

$$h=\frac{3V}{\pi \frac{h^2}{4}} \\ h^3 =\frac{12V}{\pi} \\ h =\sqrt[3]{\frac{12V}{\pi}} $$

Answer (score 1):

Volume of cone,

$V = \frac13 \pi r^2 h$.

Here, $2r =h $ or $r = \frac h2$. So,

$V = \frac13 \pi \cdot\frac{h^2}{4}\cdot h = \frac{\pi}{12} h^3 \Rightarrow \boxed{h = \left(\frac{12V}{\pi}\right)^{1/3}}$